# How can I build a msbuild project into different folders?

Tags: msbuild

Have a good day. Most likely they solved such questions, but, in my case, the option p:/OutputPath and p:/OutDir do not work. gives an error like this - MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.

I also googled it, wrote something like changing a parameter in csproj.
But, my senior colleague before leaving did not recommend replacing something in the project itself.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I tried like this:

```
p:/OutputPath=C:\Jenkins\workspace\Api\Api_DEV\API_Build_Master\Various/p:/AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false/p:Build=True/t:Clean,Rebuild
```

Desired output, I want to build the msbuild project depending on the branch.
That is, if the parameter branch = master, then build the project in

```
"C:\Jenkins\workspace\Api\Api_DEV\API_Build_Master\Master"
```

If not, then in

```
"C:\Jenkins\workspace\Api\Api_DEV\API_Build_Master\Various"
```

Maybe you can do it like this: C:\Jenkins\workspace\Api\Api_DEV\API_Build_Master%branch%"

Doing in step msbuild jenkins